# I don't understand LocalDate#compareTo() Java method return value

Tags: java, compareto, localdate

I'm trying to get skilled on dates using them with Java and the LocalDate class, there's something I don't understand about the compareTo method return value, though.

I thought that the `nextDate.compareTo(previousDate)` I'm using would return:

- 0 when dates are the same
- > 0 when the argument is before the date calling the method
- < 0 when the argument is after the date calling the method

But i thought it was safe to say that the >0 return value and the <0 value were the span of time in terms of days, equals to nextDate - previousDate.

E.g. (yyyy-MM-dd):

- 2030/01/31 - 2030/01/01 = 30
- 2030/01/03 - 2030/01/01 = 2
- 2030/02/03 - 2030/01/31 = 3

According to the following tests, this is not always true and I don't understand why.

```
package com.mycompany.provalocaldatenuovo;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class UI {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // Test 1
        LocalDate previousDate1 = LocalDate.of(2030, 01, 01);
        LocalDate nextDate1 = LocalDate.of(2030, 01, 31);

        // Test 2
        LocalDate previousDate2 = LocalDate.of(2030, 01, 01);
        LocalDate nextDate2 = LocalDate.of(2030, 01, 03);

        // Test 3
        LocalDate previousDate3 = LocalDate.of(2030, 01, 31);
        LocalDate nextDate3 = LocalDate.of(2030, 02, 03);

        // Test 4
        LocalDate previousDate4 = LocalDate.of(2030, 1, 31);
        LocalDate nextDate4 = LocalDate.of(2030, 1, 31);

        // Test 1 - expected 30
        System.out.println("TEST 1: " + nextDate1.compareTo(previousDate1));

        // Test 2 - expected 2
        System.out.println("TEST 2: " + nextDate2.compareTo(previousDate2));

        // Test 3 - expected 3
        System.out.println("TEST 3: " + nextDate3.compareTo(previousDate3));

        // Test 4 - expected 0
        System.out.println("TEST 4: " + nextDate4.compareTo(previousDate4));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
TEST 1: 30
TEST 2: 2
TEST 3: 1    //??? doesn't matter which day on february is, this will result 1
TEST 4: 0
```

Do you know what's going on TEST3?

Comment: The return value itself is *completely irrelevant*, beyond whether it is equal to, greater than or less than zero.

Comment: Andy is right. If you want to get the number of days between two `LocalDate` instances, use `firstDate.until(secondDate)` or `Period.between(firstDate, secondDate)`.

Comment: Your Localdate.compareTo() is comparing and returning the first difference it gets. If you change the Year, you will get the difference in the year. If you keep the year same and change month, you will get the difference in the month (This is what happening in Test 3). It will same for the days if you keep year and month same in both dates.

Comment: @RobSpoor thank you for the tip: this actually solved my problem in a bigger app

Comment: @VikasChoudhary this makes sense, I understand. Thank you!

Comment: @Phoenix you're welome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*At a guess*, what is going on here is that it's returning:

- The difference in years if the years are different;
- The difference in months if the year is equal but the months are different;
- The difference in days if the year and month are equal.

However, this isn't really important: the only thing you should be considering about the return value is *its sign*:

- A negative number means that `a < b`;
- Zero means that `a == b`;
- A positive number means that `a > b`.

The exact value itself (other than zero) is completely irrelevant, and subject to change if the internal implementation changes. You should only ever compare the result of `compareTo` (or `compare`) with zero, e.g. `result < 0, result >= 0` etc.

---

In the specific case of `LocalDate` (and other `java.time` classes), methods are provided to make the intent of the check more apparent:

- [`a.isBefore(b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)) corresponds to `a.compareTo(b) < 0`;
- [`a.isAfter(b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isAfter(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)) corresponds to `a.compareTo(b) > 0`.

It's up to you (or your team style) as to which to prefer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is exactly what is going on. Thank you for the answer!